# oracle how to use schema different from current user?

Tags: oracle, schema, sqlplus

I was given an oracle connection, SID=xcom, and user=sa. I connect using sqlplus, but when I do a "describe table" it says it doesn't exist:

```
SQL> describe equip_inst;
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object equip_inst does not exist
SQL>
```

I need to include the schemaname "newpoc" in order to get it:

```
SQL> describe newpoc.equip_inst;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
```

So, what's the trick? I want to login as have as default this schema name of "newpoc" for all my objects.

Comment: you probably don't have the privileges to read from the `equip_inst` table. What does `select owner from all_tables where table_name = 'EQUIP_INST'` show you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in your example you are describing that all permissions were granted accordingly, you can execute

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = <schema name>
```

In your case, as user "sa" execute:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = NEWPOC ;
```

So, in your example:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SA"
SQL>
SQL> desc equip_inst
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object equip_inst does not exist


SQL> alter session set current_schema = NEWPOC ;

Session altered.

SQL> desc equip_inst
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(100)

SQL>
```

Regards